# how to change default options of vim editor permanently?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, vim, command-line

I'm working on `vim` editor and want to edit some default options provided by *vim editor*.

i.e **N+G(5G) to move to nth line but I want N+Enter to move to nth line**

likewise:

> ***^*** want change to ***s***
>
> ***$*** want change to ***e***

etc

Comment: Anything you want to do permanently goes into `~/.vimrc`. Also, [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com). And how to change things permanently and how to make *those* changes are two different questions. *And* I get the impression you want to make Vim "simpler" for you. That is understandable in the short term, but is doing you a disservice in the long run. `^` means start-of-line and `$` end-of-line in many more environments than just Vim, so you better get used to it...

Comment: permanently means i want to save changes to ~/.vimrc file, but what code i have to write in ~/.vimrc file.
thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Check the second half of my comment. You shouldn't, really.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Should I have to move this question in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange now @jww

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the right terminology, you should be able to look up these simple tasks in the excellent and comprehensive `:help`.

*Options* influence the behavior of Vim. For example, `:set wrap` enables (soft) line breaking of long lines. You'll find it under `:help 'wrap'`; options are wrapped in single quotes in the help; `:help options` has them all.

That's not what you're after, though. You want to **change the keys that trigger certain, built-in behavior**. That's called *mapping*, documented under `:help mapping`.

To make `<Enter>` do the same thing as `G` (in *normal mode*), you'd use

```
:nnoremap <Enter> G
```

`:help key-notation` helps with how you specify the keys. [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion. The `[N]` count is separate from the command itself; you can ignore it here.

Likewise, you can do:

```
:nnoremap s ^
:nnoremap e $
```

However, note that this will override very useful built-in commands (`s` replaces the current `[count]` characters and starts editing, `e` moves to the end of word; you can look these up with `:help s` and `:help e`). Vim has attracted so many followers because of its very efficient mode-based command model; if you instead try to reconfigure Vim heavily, you're commiting a typical beginner's mistake!

#### Persistence

All the above commands only persist for the current Vim session, so you can safely try them out. To make them permanent, put them into a `~/.vimrc` configuration file (`:help vimrc`), and restart Vim. The `:` prefix is optional in that file; scripts use *Ex mode*, not normal mode.